# Enable Krpano on desktop to fullscreen mode when button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, krpano

How can I enable fullscreen mode when a button is clicked?

I think I'm want to use krpano.set(fullscreen,true);

I have an image in a slideshow with a play button over it.
When the button is clicked the slideshow stops and the pano should go fullscreen and I'll add a close full screen button. How can I trigger the API to go fullscreen?

```
   $('#panoButton').on('click',function(){

      $('.workArticleSlider').cycle('pause');

      $(this).siblings('.panoFrame').show().css('top', '0');

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To access features of KRPano from Javascript, the simplest is to call "call()".

For instance:

```
$('#krpanoSWFObject').call("plugin['info'].onclick();");
```

BUT you should know that fullscreen is a feature that **is not accessible outside of KRPano** for some security issue. Thus, you CAN try to call:

```
$('#krpanoSWFObject').call("switch(fullscreen);"); // direct call
// Or if you have a fullscreen button IN KRPano, let's say a plugin 'openfs':
$('#krpanoSWFObject').call("plugin['info'].onclick();");
```

But that WON'T work.

Sorry,

Answer (score -1):

Just try:

```
$('#krpanoSWFObject').call("calc();");
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.